# Set of all odd complex polynomials - complex vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers

Is the set of all odd complex polynomials a complex vector space?

I'm given the following definition of a vector space:

**A vector space** $V$ over the field $\mathbb F$ is a set $V$ of vectors, a field $\mathbb F$ of scalars, an addition $u+v$ of vectors $u$ and $v$, and a scalar multiplication $\lambda v$ of a scalar $\lambda$ and a vector $v$ satisfying:

1) $V$ is an abelian group with respect to the operation $+$

2) If $\lambda \in \mathbb F,$ and $v \in V$, then $\lambda v \in V$

3) $\forall$ $\lambda,\mu, v, w$, $(\lambda + \mu )v=\lambda v+\mu v$ and $\lambda(v + w)=\lambda v+ \lambda w$

4) $\forall \lambda, \mu,v,~$ $\lambda (\mu v)=(\lambda \mu)v $

5)$\forall v,~ 1v=v$, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb F$

Now let us consider the set of odd complex polynomials, such that $p(-z)=-p(z).$

Taking arbitrary odd $p_1(z),p_2(z)$, we can see that $p_1(-z)+p_2(-z)=-(p_1(z)+p_2(z))$, thus the set is closed under addition. Associativity and commutativity follow trivially from addition of complex numbers. Taking identity element $0$ and inverse of $p(z)$ to be $-p(z)$, we see that set of odd complex polynomials is indeed an abelian group with respect to addition.

Further, considering arbitrary $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$, $~\lambda p(-z)=-\lambda p(z)$ satisfying property $2)$.

Rest follows trivially from complex addition and multiplication defined in the usual way, showing that this set is indeed a complex vector space.

My question is, did I leave mistakes anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: Looks good. Basically you just need to demonstrate that the odd polynomials are a subspace of the set of polynomials. This just means shows that the space is closed under sums and scalar multiplications, which you have done.

Comment: Thanks! Subspaces will be the topic later, thus had to stick to full definition :)